# Log file roll over to new file still logs are rolling in previous day

Tags: java, log4j

I have Log 4j configured to roll over daily at mid night.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM  "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender  name="appender"  class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/data/log/engine.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="datePattern" value="'.'MM-dd-yyyy" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %p - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
 </appender>
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- <param name="ConversionPattern"    value="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>  -->
         <!-- <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %p (%M-%L)- %m%n"/> -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %%-5p %d %l - %m%n"/>

        </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <priority value ="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="appender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

During midnight setfile is called .But logs are rolling in current log as well as previous day log.Why it is still rolling in previous day log?

Comment: Which log4j version are you using. And why don't you want the previous day logs to be rolled? Do you just want to keep the history of a single day?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear My logs are rolling in both current and previous day.Once the day is done it is rolling the file with date as filename.But still same logs are there in both current and yesterday's log